# "Desktop Settings" isn't available in Arch-Linux Xfce4's Settings Manager. How can I add/install it?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, theme, xfwm4, metacity

Images:

- Settings Manager in Linux Mint [image]
- Settings Manager in Arch Linux [image]

The above images are captured on my system running Linux Mint and Arch Linux respectively.

---

The main reason I want to do this is to change every window buttons (shade, hide, max. and min.) to the same theme.

In the Linux Mint Xfce4 Settings-Manager, the "Desktop Settings" settings is available, but in the Arch Linux Xfce4 Settings-Manager, it isn't.

I want the "Desktop Settings" settings, using which I can change my windows-manager to either 'Metacity+Compositing' or only 'Metacity', because the theme I select in "Appearence" settings doesn't gets applied to apps like Thunar or XFCE Terminal if I use the default xfwm4 theme, which makes the gui inconsistent (As a temporary fix, I've to look for matching xfwm4 themes online).

But when I use 'Metacity' or 'Metacity+Compositing', all the windows, irrespective of being GTK or QT, uses the same theme, configured in the "Appearence" settings.

Also: I've installed Metacity using Pacman, but couldn't find it listed under the startup applications in "Session and Startup" settings.

The theme i want to apply is the in-built Adwaita-GTK(2,3) theme, but I couldn't find any similar matching xfwm4 theme.

So, is there any way to apply 'Metacity' or 'Metacity+Compositing' with or without the "Desktop Settings" settings. I've  also asked this questions in other communities, if anyone is facing this same issue, then they can check out the links below (I'll be adding those links soon):

- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469316/desktop-settings-isnt-available-in-xfce4s-settings-manager-how-can-i-add-in)

My System Specifications (if required):

- CPU: Intel Pentium G2030
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics (rare edition, doesn't has any number like HD 4000 or 2000 or like that)
- RAM: 2GB DDR3 1600Mhz Single Channel (⁠٥-⁠_-)
- Dedicated-GPU: None ⁠[⁠-⁠_⁠-⁠]
- Hard-Disk: WD Green 500GB 7200RPM HDD

Comment: BTW, Do I need to install any xfce4-plugin using Pacman to enable that feature/settings or something?

Comment: Thanks @muru for fixing my post. Really appreciate your efforts!